# How to subscribe to multiple events in an AWS AppSync client?

Tags: android, graphql, aws-appsync

We're currently trying to implement multiple subscriptions in our Android client and are facing some pretty weird behavior.

One subscription is working just fine. But when we subscribe to another event it seems that the latter is blocking the first subscription.
The thing is that there are any examples out there which cover two or more subscriptions.

This is what we came up with so far:

```
private AppSyncSubscriptionCall orderSubscriptionWatcher;
private AppSyncSubscriptionCall receiptSubscriptionWatcher;

private void subscribeToEvents() {
  AWSAppSyncClient awsAppSyncClient = ClientFactory.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

  AddedOrderSubscription addedOrderSubscription = AddedOrderSubscription.builder().build();
  orderSubscriptionWatcher = awsAppSyncClient.subscribe(addedOrderSubscription);
  orderSubscriptionWatcher.execute(orderSubCallback);

  AddedReceiptSubscription addedReceiptSubscription = AddedReceiptSubscription.builder().build();
  receiptSubscriptionWatcher = awsAppSyncClient.subscribe(addedReceiptSubscription);
  receiptSubscriptionWatcher.execute(receiptSubCallback);
}
```

Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using API Key? If so you'll need to use a different authentication method.

Comment: Yes, we're using authentication via api_key. So this feature will never be supported?

Comment: You can open multiple subscriptions with an API key in AppSync but the service doesn't have an identity to track when you're using API Key, so you need to manage the multiple subscriptions locally in your app. This is done today in the JS SDK but not currently in the iOS/Android SDKs. It's being looked at for those platforms too.